# How to import from '@somefolder' in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, import

I was going through someone's code and found this:

```
import { NGSWUpdateService } from '@ngsw/ngsw-update.service';
```

The developer has been able to use `'@ngsw/ngsw-update.service'` instead of original very long path `'src/client/app/shared/ngsw/ngsw-update.service'`.

So how to implement the above so that I don't have to import from relatively long paths.

[Here's the code.](https://github.com/EreckGordon/angular-universal-pwa-starter-deploy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import from a path that is not relative, it'll look into the `node_modules` folder.

So here, it's just looking for the file `ngsw-update.service` here: `node_modules/@ngsw/ngsw-update.service`.

That's the most basic use case but you can only use that those kind of paths with files from your project by defining them into `tsconfig.json` (within compilerOptions.paths`, see that article for more: https://netbasal.com/sexier-imports-in-typescript-e3c645bdd3c6

Comment: Ahh I got that he has defined @ngsw path inside `tsconfig.json` like this
```"paths": {
      "@ngsw/*": ["src/client/app/shared/ngsw/*"]```

Comment: Yep that's normal then, it's to avoid ending up with really long imports ;)